# Prestashop 1.7.3 500 server error

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I accidentally deleted the root/cache/ folder in my prestashop 1.7 project and I got 500 server error even though I restored the deleted files back. How do I fix this, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe missing chmod 777 on the cache folder?

Comment: I dont find chmod 777 where do i find that sir?

Comment: That are the directory permissions for the cache folder. Presta should be able to write something inside the cache dir. If you have ssh access, chmod is the command, if you have ftp access, you should change it somewhere in your ftp client

Comment: im still working on localhost sir.

Comment: even on localhost you should have an console/terminal - and if not, your file manager should be able to do this as well